# What current rating should I be looking for on a Battery Management System?

Tags: batteries, robot

I'm designing a power hungry robot and this is my first time constructing a battery pack. Specifically, I am going to use a 3(series) x4(parallel) 18650 battery pack using these [Samsung 35E](https://www.18650batterystore.com/Samsung-18650-p/samsung-35e.htm) cells. The calculated max current draw on this battery pack would come out to be 32 amps. When finding a Battery Management System, should I be looking for one with a max current rating above or below([like this one](https://www.banggood.com/3S-11_1V-25A-18650-Li-ion-Lithium-Battery-BMS-Protection-PCB-Board-With-Balance-Function-p-1120250.html?rmmds=search&cur_warehouse=CN)) the calculated 32 amps of the battery pack?

Answer (score 1):

Above obviously, otherwise you restrict the power available or damage something in use.

Also make sure you have sufficient fuses.